# start build service

Tags: tfs, build, service

I have a TFS2008 machine as our Source Control and configured a separate machine.

When I try to 'Start' the Build Service 2010 in other machine, I keep getting the Error:
"Cannot register Team Foundation Build Service: Unable to retrieve the registration information for 'AdminstrationService'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a TFS 2010 Build Service with a TFS 2008 server. You'll need to upgrade your server to TFS 2010 first.